# Read nested JSON from an URL with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I know there're some similar questions, but none seem to help me with what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to create a DataFrame with only the info from "data"

My JSON file looks like this [(complete file)](https://es.datachile.io/api/data?measures=Abandonment%20Percentage&drilldowns=Education%20Level,Year&parents=true&Comuna=298)

```
{
"data": [
    {
    "ID Education Level": 1,
    "Education Level": "Enseñanza Básica",
    "ID Year": 2017,
    "Year": "2017",
    "ID Region": 8,
    "Region": "Biobío",
    "ID Comuna": 298,
    "Comuna": "San Pedro De La Paz",
    "Abandonment Percentage": 0.006858621805241022
    },
    {
    "ID Education Level": 2,
    "Education Level": "Enseñanza Media",
    "ID Year": 2017,
    "Year": "2017",
    "ID Region": 8,
    "Region": "Biobío",
    "ID Comuna": 298,
    "Comuna": "San Pedro De La Paz",
    "Abandonment Percentage": 0.01564914992272025
    },
    {
    "ID Education Level": 1,
    "Education Level": "Enseñanza Básica",
    "ID Year": 2016,
    "Year": "2016",
    "ID Region": 8,
    "Region": "Biobío",
    "ID Comuna": 298,
    "Comuna": "San Pedro De La Paz",
    "Abandonment Percentage": 0.006825490582135591
    }
],
"source": [
    {
    "measures": [
        "Abandonment Percentage"
    ],
    "annotations": {
        "source_name": "Creciendo con Derechos - Ministerior de Desarrollo Social",
        "source_description": "Sistema de indicadores para el seguimiento de los derechos de niños, niñas y adolescentes, en relación a sus condiciones de vida y en sintonía con la Convención sobre los Derechos del Niño.",
        "source_link": "http://www.creciendoconderechos.gob.cl/indicadores",
        "dataset_name": "mds_abandonment_rate",
        "dataset_link": "https://github.com/datachile/datachile-etl/tree/master/childhood/mds_abandonment_rate",
        "topic": "childhood",
        "subtopic": "abandonment_rate",
        "available_dimensions": "",
        "available_measures": ""
    },
    "name": "mds_abandonment_rate",
    "substitutions": []
    }
]
}
```

And this is the DataFrame I'd like to accomplish.

[expected dataframe result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVXlE.png)

I've read the read_json documentation and seen a few solutions that might be too complex for what I'm trying to do. Also I need to work with an array of urls with JSON similar to this one, so working it manually is not really an option.

Thanks for any reply, first time asking here and excuse my poor english.

Comment: data = mydict['Data'] then df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to generate the desired output in the image

```
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('data.json') as json_file:
data = json.load(json_file)

df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
df.to_csv("output4_9.csv", encoding='utf-8', index='false')
```

The csv contains the output from it.

Here is the code to convert url to .json file:
        urllib.request import urlopen
        import json
        import requests

```
    url = "https://es.datachile.io/api/data?measures=Abandonment%20Percentage&drilldowns=Education%20Level,Year&parents=true&Comuna=298"
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(response.read())

    with open('data1.json', 'w') as fw:
        json.dump(data, fw)
```

Comment: Thing is I need to get the json from an url, how do you replace the data.json? https://es.datachile.io/api/data?measures=Abandonment%20Percentage&drilldowns=Education%20Level,Year&parents=true&Comuna=298

Answer (score 0):

If you want read json from some url then read the url from requests library and parse it as json to the variable 'data'

```
import requests
link = 'https://es.datachile.io/api/data?measures=Abandonment%20Percentage&drilldowns=Education%20Level,Year&parents=true&Comuna=298'
resp = requests.get(url=link)
if resp.status_code == 200:
    data = resp.json()
```

The rest of solution is mentioned above. I hope this helps.